# Suggested Exception type to raise for reaching maximum connection limit

Tags: python, exception

I have a connection manager that works as follows:

```
def connect(self):
    if len(connections) >= max_connections:
        raise RuntimeError("Cannot initiate new connection.")
```

Is a `RuntimeError` the proper error to raise in this circumstance, or what would be a better approach?

Comment: You could make your own exception class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use [`ConnectionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError) for errors related to connection issues.
In your case, you are looking at something like **`MaxConnectionLimitReachedError`** which you could potentially subclass from `ConnectionError` as follows.

```py
class MaxConnectionLimitReachedError(ConnectionError):
    """
    Exception raised for errors occurring from maximum number 
    of connections limit being reached/exceeded.

    Attributes:
        message -- explanation of the error
        total_connections -- total number of connections when the error occurred (optional)
        max_connections -- maximum number of connections allowed (optional)
    """

    def __init__(self, message, total_connections = None, max_connections = None):
        self.total_connections = total_connections
        self.max_connections = max_connections
        self.message = message
```

> **Your use-case would then look like as follows**:

```py
def connect(self):
    if len(connections) >= max_connections:
        message = "Maximum connection limit ({}) reached. Cannot initiate new connection."
        raise MaxConnectionLimitReachedError(message.format(max_connections))
```